# Why won't my text effect work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one folder with contents "index.html" and "js.js"
in "index.html" i have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    $(document).ready() -> 
    $("#mycontainer").unscramble();
}
</script>
<p id="mycontainer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and in "js.js":

```
(function($) {

    function shuffle(a) {
        var i = a.length, j;
        while (i) {
            var j = Math.floor((i--) * Math.random());
            var t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
    }

    function randomAlphaNum() {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 62);
        if (rnd >= 52) return String.fromCharCode(rnd - 4);
        else if (rnd >= 26) return String.fromCharCode(rnd + 71);
        else return String.fromCharCode(rnd + 65);
    }

    $.fn.rot13 = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/[a-z0-9]/ig, function(chr) {
                var cc = chr.charCodeAt(0);
                if (cc >= 65 && cc <= 90) cc = 65 + ((cc - 52) % 26);
                else if (cc >= 97 && cc <= 122) cc = 97 + ((cc - 84) % 26);
                else if (cc >= 48 && cc <= 57) cc = 48 + ((cc - 43) % 10);
                return String.fromCharCode(cc);
            }));
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.scrambledWriter = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), progress = 0, replace = /[^\s]/g,
                random = randomAlphaNum, inc = 3;
            $ele.text('');
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                $ele.text(str.substring(0, progress) + str.substring(progress, str.length).replace(replace, random));
                progress += inc
                if (progress >= str.length + inc) clearInterval(timer);
            }, 100);
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.typewriter = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), progress = 0;
            $ele.text('');
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                $ele.text(str.substring(0, progress++) + (progress & 1 ? '_' : ''));
                if (progress >= str.length) clearInterval(timer);
            }, 100);
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.unscramble = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), replace = /[^\s]/,
                state = [], choose = [], reveal = 25, random = randomAlphaNum;

            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (str[i].match(replace)) {
                    state.push(random());
                    choose.push(i);
                } else {
                    state.push(str[i]);
                }
            }

            shuffle(choose);
            $ele.text(state.join(''));

            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                var i, r = reveal;
                while (r-- && choose.length) {
                    i = choose.pop();
                    state[i] = str[i];
                }
                for (i = 0; i < choose.length; i++) state[choose[i]] = random();
                $ele.text(state.join(''));
                if (choose.length == 0) clearInterval(timer);
            }, 100);
        });
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

The the effect I want is the [Unscramble Effect](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/text-effects.html) but somehow I can't get it to work locally. Can someone please help me out? I wasted a lot of time on google already.

EDIT:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mycontainer").unscramble();
}
</script>
<p id="mycontainer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I did edit the "index.hmtl" And in the console I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: I can't see jQuery included anywhere

Comment: You need to include jquery as well before including `js.js` Look at your console for errors.

Comment: What does your JavaScript console say? Take a look at it when you are having issues.

Comment: Unexpected end of input usually indicates a missing `}`... Chrome since V8 is for some reason still not pointing out WHERE the error is encountered which is annoying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jquery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**before** you include your `js.js`.

The unscramble functions are extensions of the jQuery library.

As @PSL and @JustinWood have suggested, you can check your JAvascript Console and there will likely be a "jQuery is undefined" function error which would have gotten you closer to a solution.

Consoles are available in Chrome and IE by default and I use the firebug extension with Firefox.

Comment: Do you mean firebug for Firefox? or is there a Firebug on IE now?

Comment: yeah I meant Firefox... oops